# Turn Python list from CSV with multi-value fields into a Python nested list, sort nested list values and export to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, nested

I have used the Python `csv` module to turn a `csv` with multi-value fields into a Python `list`. The output contains fields with multiple values that are related.

```
['Route', 'Vehicles', 'Vehicle Class', 'Driver_ID', 'Date', 'Start', 'Arrive']
['ABC', 'ZYG098, AB0134, GF0158', 'A1, B2, C3', 'John Doe, Jane Doe, Abraham Lincoln', '20150301', 'A', 'B']
['AC', 'ZGA123', 'C3', 'George Washington', '20150301', 'A', 'C']
['ABC', 'XAZ012, AB0134, YZ089', 'C1, B2, A2 ', 'John Adams, Jane Doe, Thomas Jefferson', '20150302', 'A', 'B']
```

I would like to turn the Vehicles, Vehicle Class and Driver ID fields into a nested list so that if I sort each sub-list within Vehicle `row[1]` to ensure the vehicles always appear in alphabetical order in the sublist and, that the Vehicle Class and Driver stay in the respective, correct orders. So the header and first row sub-lists would be arranged like:

```
['Route', 'Vehicles', 'Vehicle Class', 'Driver_ID', 'Date', 'Start', 'Arrive']
['ABC', 'AB0134, GF0158, ZYG098', 'B2, C3, A1', 'Jane Doe, Abraham Lincoln, John Doe', '20150301', 'A', 'B']
['AC', 'ZGA123', 'C3', 'George Washington', '20150301', 'A', 'C']
['ABC', 'AB0134, YZ089, XAZ012', 'B2, A2, C1', 'Jane Doe, Thomas Jefferson, John Adams', '20150302', 'A', 'B']
```

So in the output above each of the sub-groups/lists for Vehicles is sorted alphabetically and the Vehicle Class and Driver_ID are re-arranged as necessary to retain their original relationship with their respective Vehicles (i.e. Driver ID - John Doe drove Vehicle - ZYG098 which was Vehicle Class - A1, so those items are moved in their sub-lists to reflect that ZYG098 is now last, not first). If this can be done, how would you export the resulting nested list back to a CSV with the original headers?

Apologies if this is simple or ridiculous, I am just starting to learn Python.  If a nested list is not the best option, I am open to any other solution (for a dictionary, I would need to join fields to create a key, as there is no unique key without combining Route_Date). If anyone has a solid resource for handling a wide range of CSV use cases with Python a recommendation would be great.

Thank you in advance for your patience and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally on the same page, it took a bit of work but this will do what you want:

```
from itertools import chain
import csv


l = [['Route', 'Vehicles', 'Vehicle Class', 'Driver_ID', 'Date', 'Start', 'Arrive'],
     ['ABC', 'ZYG098, AB0134, GF0158', 'A1, B2, C3', 'John Doe, Jane Doe, Abraham Lincoln', '20150301', 'A', 'B'],
     ['AC', 'ZGA123', 'C3', 'George Washington', '20150301', 'A', 'C'],
     ['ABC', 'XAZ012, AB0134, YZ089', 'C1, B2, A2 ', 'John Adams, Jane Doe, Thomas Jefferson', '20150302', 'A', 'B']]
it = map(list,zip(*l))

# transpose original list, row-columns, columns-rows
it =  zip(*l)

# get each column separately, using iter so we can pop first element
# off to get headers efficiently 
route, veh, veh_c, d_id, date, start, arrive = iter(iter(next(it))), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it))

# get all headers to write later
headers = next(route), next(veh), next(veh_c), next(d_id), next(date), next(start), next(arrive)

srt_veh = []
key_inds = []

# sort vehicle elements and keep a record of old indexes
# so subelements in Vehicle_class and driver_id can be rearranged to match
for x in veh:
    srt = sorted(x.split(","))
    key_inds.append([x.split(",").index(w) for w in srt])
    srt_veh.append(",".join(srt).strip())

srt_veh_cls = []

# sort vehicle class based on old index of elements in vehicles
# and rejoin split elements
for ind, ele in enumerate(veh_c):
    spl = ele.split(",")
    srt_veh_cls.append(",".join([spl[i].strip() for i in key_inds[ind]]))

srt_dr_id = []

# sort driver_ids  based on old index of elements in vehicle
# and join subelements again after splitting and sorting
for ind, ele in enumerate(d_id):
    spl = ele.split(",")
    srt_dr_id.append(",".join([spl[i].strip() for i in key_inds[ind]]))

 # transpose again for writing
zipped = zip(*(route, srt_veh, srt_veh_cls,
           srt_dr_id, date, start, arrive))
```

finally write with csv.writerows:

```
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(headers)
    wr.writerows(zipped)
```

Output:

```
Route,Vehicles,Vehicle Class,Driver_ID,Date,Start,Arrive
ABC,"AB0134, GF0158,ZYG098","B2,C3,A1","Jane Doe,Abraham Lincoln,John Doe",20150301,A,B
AC,ZGA123,C3,George Washington,20150301,A,C
ABC,"AB0134, YZ089,XAZ012","B2,A2,C1","Jane Doe,Thomas Jefferson,John Adams",20150302,A,B
```

For python 2 replace zip with  `itertools.izip` and map with `itertools.imap`:

```
from itertools import izip, imap
```

You could zip more and a do a few things to shorten the code  but I think that would not help the readability.

Comment: Thank you very much, my apologies, I poorly explained the way I wanted to sort.  I intended to sort each Vehicle sublist into alphabetical order and maintain the respective correct orders for Vehicle Class and Driver_ID.  I updated the original post to clarify, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: same logic we just need to add an extra loop, i will edit, you just want the one column sorted?

Comment: @Triadelphia, check the edit and see if we are on the same page

Comment: Padraic, not really the column sorted, but each sublist within the column. I need to arrange each sub-list in the Vehicle column in alphabetical order, but also re-arrange the Vehicle Class and Driver_ID sub-list for each row to keep the relationship.  No need to sort an entire column, but to sort the sublists within each row.  I included an example of the desired output in the original post, with the ordered Vehicles and the rearranged Vehicle Class and Driver_ID based on the sorted Vehicle sub-list.  Thanks again

Comment: so basically you want `['ABC', 'ZYG098, AB0134, GF0158', 'A1, B2, C3', 'John Doe, Jane Doe, Abraham Lincoln', '20150301', 'A', 'B']` sorted?

Comment: I want to sort each Vehicles field alphabetically so the same combination of vehicles always appears in the same order for data analysis.  But I need to somehow nest the vehicle type and Driver_ID with Vehicles, so if the sub-list (multi-value cell from a csv) is sorted from

Comment: ok still slightly confused, why is `'AB0134, GF0158, ZYG098'` where it is in your expected output and the only thing sorted?

Comment: I added how it would ideally appear in the original question, hopefully that will help make sense.

Comment: I understand finally I think, you want to sort each vehicle substring and move the other substring elements based on the new position of the sorted substrings in vehicle

Comment: Because ZYG098 has properties Vehicle Class - A1 and Driver_ID - John Doe.  Since ZYG098 is now third in the sorted sub-list, both the Vehicle Class and Driver_ID corresponding to ZYG098 have to be shifted to match the same position as ZYG098 is in the sorted sub-list.  Is it possible to do this by making grouping the lists correctly?  Sorry, I don't think I am explaining this well.

Comment: It is ok. I get what you are trying to do, it is pretty tricky. I will have a crack at later

Comment: @Triadelphia, have a look at the new answer, it should work, That was a tricky problem!

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience Padraic -- apologies, was traveling for a few days and finally got some time to get back to this.  I can't wait to dig through and try this!

Comment: Receiving TypeError: list object is not an iterator an error related to line 16 <in module> 

    route, veh, veh_c, d_id, date, start, arrive = iter(iter(next(it))), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it)), iter(next(it))

Comment: are you using python2?

Comment: Yes, but I switched to a 3.3 environment in Anaconda and received the same error. If I use izip and imap instead of chain, would I need to modify the use of iter?  

When I simplified it, the problem I have is using next against a list object, even with those imported.  Would switching to a full installation of python 3 avoid this issue?

Comment: are you actually replacing zip with izip and map with imap in the code, not just importing?

Comment: I had not replaced imap, worked perfectly the first time, thank you very much. Definitely going to learn these modules and put serious time into Python now.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to something like nested format you describe:

```
nested = zip(*lst)
```

And zip is its own inverse:

```
orig = zip(*nested)
```

But maybe what you really want is:

```
import operator

sort = sorted(lst[1:], key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Which gives you a new list sorted by row 1. In this case you haven't changed the format of the data, so you should be able to dump it back out as csv without modification, although you'd need to prepend the original headers from lst[0].

Comment: Thank you very much, my apologies, I poorly explained the way I wanted to sort.  I intended to sort each Vehicle sublist into alphabetical order and maintain the respective correct orders for Vehicle Class and Driver_ID.   I updated the original post to clarify, hopefully it makes more sense now.